# Yield return results of another Enumerable of the same datatype

Tags: c#, yield-return

I am writing validation logic, and I wanted the caller to only get the number of validation messages they really need (some cases, just the first validation message is necessary, other times, we want to now all of the problems with the given data)

Given this, I thought "Brilliant! I'll return an IEnumerable, and use the yield return each of the results. if FirstOrDefault() is used on the enumeration, only the first failed validation will be executed, where as the following will be skipped, unless we call ToList() on the validation result enumerable.

The issue I am seeing is if I want to break my validation logic into multiple methods, each returning an Enumerable, I have to enumerate over THAT set with another yield return there as well. (see simplified example below)

```
public IEnumerable<string> Validate(ClassToValidate obj)
{
  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Name)
  {
     yield return "empty name";
  }
  foreach(var message in ValidateSubObject(obj.OtherObjectToValidate))
  {
    yield return message;
  }
}

private IEnumerable<string> ValidateSubObject(OtherClass objToValidate)
{
   yield return ...
}
```

Is there some other keyword I am missing, where I could "yield return set" from the other method that returns another IEnumerable of the same datatype? I.E. is there a simpler syntax than:

```
  foreach(var message in ValidateSubObject(obj.OtherObjectToValidate))
  {
    yield return message;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot `yield return` multiple items. If you want to use iterator methods to concatenate sequences, you'll have to loop through them.

Of course, you could always drop the `yield return` completely and construct your `IEnumerable<T>` to be returned using other means (LINQ's `Concat` method immediately comes to mind).

```
public IEnumerable<string> Validate(ClassToValidate obj)
{
    var subObjectMessages = ValidateSubObject(obj.OtherObjectToValidate);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Name))
    {
        return new[] { "empty name" }.Concat(subObjectMessages);
    }

    return subObjectMessages;
}
```

Comment: does linq's Concat action iterate over the enumeration though? I was hoping to avoid actually executing all of the code (for example, some validation steps I want to avoid getting called if possible.

Comment: @NathanTregillus, `Concat` creates a lazy `IEnumerable` which yields (item by item) from the first collection, then the second *when it is iterated over*, so you preserve the exact behaviour described in your question.

Comment: Thank you Kirill! this is helps me understand what is occuring under the covers!

Answer (score 2):

Once you've introduced `yield` in a function, you have to stay with it.  A common approach these days is to use LINQ, which is often more flexible.

```
public IEnumerable<string> Validate(ClassToValidate obj)
{
  return (String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Name) ? new [] { "empty name" } : Enumerable.Empty<string>())
      .Concat(ValidateSubObject(obj.OtherObjectToValidate));
}
```

Comment: thank you Dan for the help! Glad for all the helpful answers!